# Brute Force Algorithm w/Java Passing String Error

Tags: java, string, static, brute-force

I think this may be a very simple solution but I am not too sure.

I am trying to create an array of characters, sort through them by incrementing a particular index of the array and throwing them into a string at the end.

I have accomplished this, (verified via printing the result out to the console. "aaaaaaaa" to "aaaaaaab" and so on. However, my new version of the code sorts through ASCII Values 33 - 126. '!' to '~'

Now, the one thing I am trying to do is call that string in the main method so that the encryption/decryption program that we were assigned, can use this string over and over again.

The program we were originally assigned can be found here:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html

```
    import java.lang.Class.*;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
    import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

public class Example1 {

public String keyGen() {
//create an array used for storing each character    
char array[] = new char[8];

    //for loop checks for each character between '!' and '~'
    for (char c0 = '!'; c0 <= '~'; c0++) {
    array[0] = c0;

    for (char c1 = '!'; c1 <= '~'; c1++) {
    array[1] = c1;

    for (char c2 = '!'; c2 <= '~'; c2++) {
    array[2] = c2;

    for (char c3 = '!'; c3 <= '~'; c3++) {
    array[3] = c3;

    for (char c4 = '!'; c4 <= '~'; c4++) {
    array[4] = c4;

    for (char c5 = '!'; c5 <= '~'; c5++) {
    array[5] = c5;

    for (char c6 = '!'; c6 <= '~'; c6++) {
    array[6] = c6;

    for (char c7 = '!'; c7 <= '~'; c7++) {
    array[7] = c7;

    //create new string that stores the array
    String pKey = new String(array);

    //trying to return the new string 
    return pKey;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }

public static void main(String []args) {
try {

// I am getting an error here; I know it has something to do with static references

    String key = new String(keyGen(pKey); 

                    // needs to be at least 8 characters for DES

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("original.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt");
        encrypt(key, fis, fos);

        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("encrypted.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("decrypted.txt");
        decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for SunJCE

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

}

Thi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you solve the problem. As for right now, your `keyGen()` is equivalent to the following code:

```
public String keyGen() {
    return "!!!!!!!!";
}
```

because you return the value as soon as you enter the innermost `for` loop. Maybe you want to change the method to return a `List<String>` and add your strings in the innermost `for` loop to that list, and return that list after all of the `for` loops? This way you could iterate through the list in your `main` method.

---

If I have counted correct, there are 93^8 = 5.595.818.096.650.401 different strings. It was bad advice to store all those in a list. Dukeling noted in the comments, that it would be better to use a custom `Iterator<String>` for that.

---

**EDIT**

Here's an implementation of such an iterator:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BruteForceIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private char min, max;

    private char[] current;

    private char[] last;

    private int reachedLast = 0;

    public BruteForceIterator(char min, char max, int length) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        current = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(current, min);
        last = new char[length];
        Arrays.fill(last, max);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return reachedLast < 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        String str = new String(current);
        for(int i = current.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char next = following(current[i]);
            current[i] = next;
            if (next != min) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Arrays.equals(current, last) || reachedLast > 0) {
            reachedLast++;
        }
        return str;
    }

    private char following(char in) {
        if (in < max) {
            return (char) (in + 1);
        } else {
            return min;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No with me, sir!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BruteForceIterator bit = new BruteForceIterator('a', 'c', 3);
        while (bit.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(bit.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattheusWardius: See my edit for such a `Iterator`. It has `main` method to demonstrate how to use it.